# jquery replaceWith mixture of quotation marks ' and "

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I have written a few lines of JQuery code that replaces an item on a list from a link to log in, to a link to log out and vice versa. It also scrolls the page back to the top.  I've had to use a mixture of single quotation and double quotation marks. Clearly, this code:

```
$('#myntamsloti').replaceWith("<li id="myntamsloto"><a href="#" onClick="javascript: $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#login').offset().top}, 600);">LogIn</a></li>");
```

gives an error as the first set of quotation marks are interpreted as the end of the statement. Switching them around lengthens the command but I can't find a combination that allows the whole line to be run. So, I've chopped the line up:

```
var htmlinsert = '<li id="myntamsloto"><a href="#" onClick="javascript: ';
htmlinsert = htmlinsert + "$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#login').offset().top}, 600);";
htmlinsert = htmlinsert + '">LogIn</a></li>';

$('#myntamsloti').replaceWith(htmlinsert);
```

It works but I've never seen this.

**Is there a more elegant way of doing it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can amend your single line of code using `replaceWith()` to use the correct quotes. You need to use different quotes to delimit the string and the attributes within it, and then escape the inner quotes where they must match those delimiting the string. Try this:

```
$('#myntamsloti').replaceWith('<li id="myntamsloto"><a href="#" onclick="javascript: $(\'html, body\').animate({scrollTop: $(\'#login\').offset().top}, 600);">LogIn</a></li>');
```

That said, the HTML would be much simpler (and better practice) to omit the outdated `onclick` attribute in the HTML to be inserted and attach an event handler using JavaScript, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#myntamsloto', function(e) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#login').offset().top
    }, 600);
});

$('#myntamsloti').replaceWith('<li id="myntamsloto"><a href="#">LogIn</a></li>');
```

Comment: Much more elegant! Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it a programmatically friendly way..

Yes it's more lines of code, but it has the added benefit that you can do a LOT more with the objects defined, and you can use scoped variables in the click handler AND your inspect source will be a lot cleaner.

```js
    $myntamsloto = $('<li id="myntamsloto">');
    $myntamslotoLink = $('<a href="#">LogIn</a>');
    $myntamslotoLink.on('click',function() {
       $('html, body').animate({
                                  scrollTop: $('#login').offset().top
                               }, 
                               600);
    });
    $myntamsloto.append($myntamslotoLink);
    $('#myntamsloto').replaceWith($myntamsloto);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="login">login</button>
<div style="height:800px;background:green;width:20px;clear:both;"></div>
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
<li id="myntamsloto">baz</li>
</ul>
```